# How to set full page background to mat-spinner

Tags: css, angular-material

I'm very green when it comes to CSS. I'm using the [angular material spinner](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview) 
, I applied CSS class to the spinner to display it with a gray background.
What else do I need to do to make the background full-page?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxzo97?file=app%2Fprogress-spinner-overview-example.css)

Comment: Add `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);` to the `body` tag or full screen covering div instead of `.spinner` to get a full-page overlay.

Comment: @thebrownkid I'm sorry, it didn't work.